# Web ViewSwift 3.0

Tags: swift

What is the difference between

```
var webView : UIWebView !
```

and

```
webView = UIWebView()   // in the viewDidLoad section
```

I mean the difference in their meaning.

Comment: The first one is the declaration of the variable, the second one the initialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var webView: UIWebView!` is the declaration of the instance variable of type UIWebView, and `webView = UIWebView()` is the initialization of that variable.

Comment: please, i am stuck in some method and need an opinion if possible;   making an app for currency exchange, i need to bring the live currency rate from bank website, to my app..How to do this ?      and for the main story board, the fetched web value is previewed in a lablel or what   ?

Comment: Hi Ali, if you are making a web request to fetch live data, you should check out Alamofire. I have used it to get live weather data from OpenWeather API. It's very popular among iOS developers. Once you retrieve and extract the data as JSON, you can use it pretty much as a String.